# Running scheduled task a period of time after another one started

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, scheduled-task

I have two scheduled task running on my Windows Server. One of them is to run a database and the other is to run an API to access the database.

I need the API task to run after the database task has started, lets say 30 seconds, to make sure the database task is running fully. If I start the API task at the same or before the database task then they both still run but the API does not work how it should.

I see that in Task Scheduler you can have to actions for one trigger, I tried this but the API task starts quicker than the database task.

I would like the API task to be reliant on the database task incase the database stops for whatever reason, when it is restarted the API task will stop and start again so that it will work correctly.

If there a way do this?

Comment: Why not just put a delay in the second task?

Comment: @GregAskew I can put a delay in the second one, but how does the second know the first one stopped and then started again?

Comment: Use an event trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a PowerShell script as the task.

It first starts the database task and then checks whether the database is running, only then is starts the API call.